# How to specify own equation numbers in context? Compared to align* in Latex?

Tags: context, equation-number

How can I reproduce this in context? I am using TL 2023

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*} 
\sin x &= \int_{0}^\infty \cos x \,dx \tag{101}  \\
\sin y &= \int_{0}^\infty \cos y \,dy  \tag{ABC}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't figure how in context to give my own equation numbers. Here is my attempt (one of many)

```
\starttext
\placeformula
    \startformula
       \startmathalignment[n=1,align=right]
          \NC  \sin x = \int_{0}^\infty \cos x \,dx   \NR
          \NC  \sin y = \int_{0}^\infty \cos y \,dy   \NR
      \stopmathalignment
    \stopformula
\stoptext
```

Compiled using `context main.tex` gives

[image]

What is the syntax to specify any equation label/number I want in the above? Same as Latex.

TL 2023

Comment: There's no good solution that I'm aware of. See [this thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/thread/KX4GXA5LZMAHBE5X6J4S73227BE27UVV/) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400257/270600) for some partial solutions. The math system has been almost completely redone in the past couple of years, so there's hopefully a better solution now.

Comment: Does this topic https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400257/tag-equation-in-context-with-arbitrary-text help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't remember if this went into TL2023 or not, but you can try this:

```
\starttext

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\startplaceformula
  \startformula
    \startalign
      \NC  \sin x \EQ \int_{0}^\infty \cos x \dd x   \NR[eq:a]
      \NC  \sin y \EQ \int_{0}^\infty \cos y \dd y   \NR[eq:b]
    \stopalign
  \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\startformula
  \startalign[text:1={(101)},text:2={(ABC)}]
    \NC  \sin x \EQ \int_{0}^\infty \cos x \dd x   \NR
    \NC  \sin y \EQ \int_{0}^\infty \cos y \dd y   \NR
  \stopalign
\stopformula

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\startformula
  \sin x \alignhere = \int_{0}^\infty \cos x \dd x \texthere[right]{(101)}
  \breakhere
  \sin y \alignhere = \int_{0}^\infty \cos y \dd y \texthere[right]{(ABC)}
\stopformula

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\stoptext
```

[image: Result]

A few comments:

- There is rarely any motivation to use align anymore. The third variant is often much easier and more natural as it is not setting the math in cells, but in one paragraph.
- `\,` is not meant to be used in ConTeXt (in fact, it might even be changed to output a comma). Here use `\dd` to get a native differential d.
- I don't understand what your `align=right` was meant to do, so I took it away.
- Within align we can use `text:1` and so on to insert text, but they are inserted to the left. No way to insert them on the right at this time. But as mentioned, the third way is preferred.

It might be interesting to know that we (well Hans is coding, I am testing) have this week added also `\numberhere` that makes the alignments even less needed. So, if I here do (no release yet, so a teaser)

```
\startformula
  \sin x \alignhere = \int_{0}^\infty \cos x \dd x \numberhere
  \breakhere
  \sin y \alignhere = \int_{0}^\infty \cos y \dd y \numberhere
\stopformula
```

after the other formulas I get

[image: numbered paragraph formulas]

Also `\numberhere[eq:foo]` can be used, so that one can refer back to it.